# How do I refer to an item in a list<object> by Key rather than index?

Tags: c#, list, key

I have a class that contains a `List<>` of objects. For this example I will say the objects are a basic class as below:

```
public class City
{
    private string name;
    private string country;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Normally I would refer to these objects like so:

```
List<City> theList = new List<City>();
City theCity = theList[0];
```

What I would like to do is refer to the list as follows:

```
List<City> theList = new List<City>();
City theCity = theList["London"];
```

Where London is the name property of one of the cities.

How do I achieve this?  At present I have been constructing "find" type methods that return me the city in question. What I need is to be able to refer by Key.

Comment: You can't be sure that there is only one item with the specified "key" in a list. Better use a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write a wrapper List class CityList and overload the [] operator.

```
public class City
{
    private string name;
    private string country;

    public City(string cityName)
    {
        Name = cityName;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }
}

public class CityList : CollectionBase
{
    public CityList() : base ()
    {
    }

    public City this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return (City)List[index];
        }
        set
        {
            List[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public City this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            int index = this.IndexOf(name);
            if (index < 0 || index >= this.List.Count) return null; // or assert

            return (City)List[index];
        }
        set
        {
            int index = this.IndexOf(name);
            if (index > 0 || index >= this.List.Count) return; // or assert
            List[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public virtual int IndexOf(City city)
    {
        return List.IndexOf(city);
    }

    public virtual int IndexOf(string name)
    {
        if (name == null) return -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < List.Count; i++)
        {
            if (((City)List[i]).Name.ToLower() == name.ToLower())
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public virtual void Insert(int index, City city)
    {
        List.Insert(index, city);
    }

    public virtual int Add(City city)
    {
        return base.List.Add(city);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        City NewYork = new City("New York");
        City Boston = new City("Boston");
        City Tampa = new City("Tampa");

        CityList cities = new CityList();
        cities.Add(NewYork);
        cities.Add(Boston);
        cities.Add(Tampa);

        Console.WriteLine(cities["Boston"].Name); // prints "Boston"

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

There might be a slicker way to do it now so you don't need the casting. This is like .NET 2.0 code.

Comment: could you give me an example of how to do this (using the basic city class example),

Thanks

Comment: i added some example code for you. i left out some methods that you'd probably implement for brevity (like addrange, remove, etc)

Comment: It's better to derive from `Collection<City>`, using `System.Collections.ObjectModel`. Then you will not have to cast. It is also possible to derive from `List<City>`, and that will be the solution that is most easy to write, but not necessarily the best one. Another way is to not derive from any collection class, and then have an accessible `List<City>` as a member of your class `CityList`.

Answer (score 9):

Basically, it sounds like you want a `Dictionary<string, City>` instead of a `List<City>`. You can easily create this with LINQ:

```
var dictionary = list.ToDictionary(city => city.Name);
```

You can use a list and search through it (as per Ethan's answer) if you really want to preserve the order, but if you *only* need to look up by name, then a dictionary is what you want.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, not sure about converting them all to dictionaries (there is more than one list) and order is important in the example i am actually working on.... thanks for replying so quickly.

Comment: or use an implementation of [`IOrderedDictionary<TKey,TValue>`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18615/OrderedDictionary-T-A-generic-implementation-of-IO)

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ:

```
List<City> theList = new List<City>();
City theCity = theList.FirstOrDefault( x => x.Name == "London" );
```

Comment: He said he's already using the List Find method, no reason to use LINQ here. It's longer and theoretically slower, although I haven't tested it.

Comment: these are small lists (the actual list items are only 20-30 long).  i didnt mention that i needed to preserve the order (but i do!).. so thank you for this suggestion

Answer (score 0):

How about `System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection`?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx